# How to use z-index from code in Android

Tags: android, z-index, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout, and I dynamically add View items . I need to get new items were located lower than the old ones.

for example:

```
MenuLayout = (LinearLayout) MainActivity.findViewById (R.id.MenuLayout);
MenuLayout.addView(newBox); //at the top
MenuLayout.addView(newBox); //lower 
MenuLayout.addView(newBox); //At the bottom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add them to a collection while you're adding them. Then you can refer to what ever the object is by the collection.

```
private ArrayList<E> collection = new ArrayList<E>();

......

    MenuLayout = (LinearLayout) MainActivity.findViewById (R.id.MenuLayout);
    MenuLayout.addView(newBox); collection.add(newBox); //index 0 in collection
    MenuLayout.addView(newBox); collection.add(newBox); //index 1 in collection
    MenuLayout.addView(newBox); collection.add(newBox); //index 2 in collection
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have all set of items. They are created and deleted dynamically.

Comment: there's no reason that such a thing would impede utilization of this method. if they're created in a loop, then you add them *while* in loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, since this is a `LinearLayout`, you are working with either the X or Y axis, not the Z axis. In Android terms, the Z axis is coming out the screen towards the user's eyes.

Also, please do not try to add the same widget `newBox` multiple times, as you will crash.

Beyond that, you access the children of a `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout` using `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()`. Children will be indexed according to the order they were added.

Comment: An example is for illustrative purposes. In the code it's different objects.